# Installing Composer on Bluehost VPS

Tags: composer-php, aws-php-sdk

I am somewhat new to all this so maybe this is a simple question. I am trying to install Composer and have read through all the documentation to the best of my understanding.

I have installed composer through bluehost's system console. Received the message that:
"Composer (version 1.6.3) successfully installed to : /root/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar"

Now when I type "php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php" into the console I get the following message:
"could not open input file: composer.phar"

I am follow the direction from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Calling it using `php composer.phar` works only if you call it from the folder where you've placed the phar. You should either add an alias such that you can call it like `composer` from everywhere (without typing php before) or call it using `php /root/composer.phar`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still get a message: "could not open input file: /root/composer.phar". I guess I just don't understand where the file is because I have tried many different versions of the above

Comment: Well just using "php composer require aws/aws-sdk-php" has worked. So thank you for your help.